# Did I do anything wrong?

Tags: discussion

I feel like I've made the user in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246653/106901) angry and it seems they have been deterred from ever using the SE again, two outcomes which I of course did not want to happen.

Was my response appropriate? Was there another way of phrasing it that would've come across better? etc.

Comment: wouldn't worry about it tbh, you did nothing wrong, it's irrelevant if he's upset as a result of you doing nothing wrong

Comment: Since you knew it was a new user, you could have at least started with "welcome to the site"

Comment: @ChaseSandmann That tends to sound very false, when followed with criticism.  "Hey, welcome here!  You did something wrong, so we can't help you."

Comment: @Frank That's rather subjective, IMHO. As a mainly lurking user, it's quite nice when someone starts w/ a positive declaration before moving to describe how I'm wrong. Emoticons help too :)

Answer (score 3):

Not from what I read.. and not from David's comments. He acknowledged that this is not the first time he has had a question closed for asking too many questions in one. His question was more of a discussion topic anyways and while it may have been able to be reworded to ask something like 'What parallels are there between CS:GO and CoD BO3' it probably would not have gotten the answer/discussion he was looking for anyways. If anything this would have been more of the type of question you ask one or two of then come into The Bridge and get your discussion.

If anything I would suggest maybe pointing out one of the easier to understands reasons why we ask for questions to be separate instead of just all of the same topic.. He asked 10 questions, what if there were 10 answers, one to each of them, which would be right? Or worse, if there are multiple answers where people get a few of them answered right and the rest wrong?

Overall though the guy said he was just going to go discuss it on the game forums.. Not that he hated this place and was never coming back.